# Process not standing by while using "read"

Tags: c, process

I want to send a username from process 1 to process 2, but process 2 finishes for no reason at all;
here's some code to be more explicit : 
Process 1 :

```
            int fd;
            fd=open("myfifo", O_RDWR);
            int l=strlen(login);
            write(fd,&l,sizeof(l));
            write(fd,login,strlen(login));
            read(fd,login,strlen(login));
```

Process 2 :

```
            int fd,l;
            mkfifo("myfifo",0666);
            fd=open("myfifo",O_RDWR);
            read(fd,&l,sizeof(l));
            read(fd,user,l);
            if (strcmp(user,reference)==0) {
                                                write(fd,"okay",5);
                                            }
            else
            {
                write(fd,"not allowed",12);
            }
```

But Process 2 doesn't stand by waiting to read from process 1, it just finishes.
Any ideas?

Comment: You do absolutely no checking for any errors.

Comment: Why do you read() in the writer?

Comment: Probably not the main issue, but since you don't send the terminating null byte over the fifo, the string `user` in process 2 won't be null terminated, so calling `strcmp` on it will not work.

Comment: please use checks and perror.

Comment: @NateEldredge well he could use larger zeroed input buffer (for user).

Comment: process 2 is sending a string that is longer than the `login` string, so will never get all the response back into process 1.  DO NOT be reading in process 1 from the FIFO that your process 1 writes into.  rather, open another FIFO.  Be sure to close and destroy those FIFOs when done with them